# Clean data form scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

How can i clear all objects out of 'game.lua, when i leave the game scene all the data is still on the screen, how can i remove everything when i leave and reset it back to the start position when i go back to 'game.lua' ?

game.lua:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight
system.setIdleTimer(false); -- Prevent the app from becoming suspended
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()
clouts = true 
score = 0
speeda1 = 100
speedb1 = 150

function scene:createScene( event )
   local group = self.view
   end

function scene:enterScene( event )
local group = self.view
--start drop zone 
if clouts then

local badclout1 = {} 
local bad1Group = display.newGroup()
local function spawnBC1()
   local badclouts1 = display.newImage("BCloud1.png")
   badclouts1.x = math.random(0, _W)
   physics.addBody( badclouts1, "dynamic", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )       
   badclouts1.name = "BCloud1" 
   badclouts1.bodyType = "kinematic"
   badclouts1.isSensor = true
   badclouts1.y = math.random(-100, -50)
   badclouts1.index = #badclout1 + 1
   bad1Group:insert(badclouts1)
   badclouts1.rotation = math.random(-10,10) -- Rotate the object
   badclouts1:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(speeda1, speedb1)) -- Drop down
   badclout1[badclouts1.index] = badclouts1
   tmrSpawn1 = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(spawna, spawnb), spawnBC1)
return badclouts1 
end
tmrSpawn1 = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(1000, 10000), spawnBC1)
 local function removeBomb()
  for i, v in pairs(badclout1) do
    if badclout1[i].y >1000 then
        badclout1[i]:removeSelf()
        badclout1[i] = nil
     end
  end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", removeBomb)

end
-- end drop zone

local function speatTimer()
   speeda1 = speeda1+1
   speedb1 = speedb1+1
end
local mainTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 550, speatTimer, 200 )

function gameOver()
   storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)
end

end

function scene:exitScene( event )
   local group = self.view
   Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
   Runtime:removeEventListener("accelerometer", onTilt)
   Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", removeBomb)
end


function scene:destroyScene( event )
   local group = self.view
end

function scene:overlayEnded( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "overlayEnded", scene )
return scene
```

Regards Kevin,

Answer (score 2):

if you are using storyboard and want to reset all the values you can remove the scene before you go to another scene so when you go again to the same scene all will be created

```
function scene:exitScene( event )
   local group = self.view
   Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
   Runtime:removeEventListener("accelerometer", onTilt)
   Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", removeBomb)
   storyboard.removeScene("SCENE TO REMOVE")
end
```

or do this after you go to the scene

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
storyboard.removeScene("SCENE TO REMOVE")
end
```

here's the link on how to implement it.
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/31/storyboard-scene-purging-vs-removal/

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to reset back your object positions and variable data

The **first** one is to create a function like this

```
function resetGame()
--your initial position and data values here
end
```

And call it whenever you need to reset your game but you will manually code the reset values.

The **second** one is by creating a dummy scene. A **dummy scene** is a scene that will redirect you again to the game scene like this

**Dummy Scene**

```
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    storyboard.gotoScene( "scenes.Game" ) --scene/Game.lua
end
```

to reset the values of your objects and variables, but don't forget to remove all of the listeners and put it on the `exitScene()` function when you go to the **dummy scene**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using storyboard, why not simply insert all your display objects into group:

```
 group:insert(someobject)
```

and let the scene manager do the work for you.  By not creating the scene in scene:createScene() your ability to transition the screen won't work.  By not putting things into the group, it can't remove them for you when the scene goes away.